# Default values in protocol extensions

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

New to using protocols here.

I have a set of viewcontrollers which uses a protocol called mainNavBarItems.

I would like the following, but my code below is hitting a range of errors:

- have a variable called rootView which defaults false
- be able to set the variable when initialzing the viewcontroller
- create a selector in the protocol extension functions

---

```
protocol mainNavBarItems {  
  var rootView:Bool {get set}
  func gotoRootProfileView()
  init()
  init(rootView:Bool)
}

extension mainNavBarItems{

  // how do i set the default to be true?
  init(rootView: Bool) {
    self.init()
    self.rootView = rootView
  }


  func addMainNavBarItems(){
    let s = self as! UIViewController
    // ERROR: using a string, but not sure how to define a selector in this case
    s.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: s, action: "gotoRootGlobalView")
  }

}


class ProfileViewController:  UIViewController, mainNavBarItems{
  func gotoRootProfileView() {
    // does stuff
  }
}

// How do i set the boolean for rootview here?
let vc:ProfileViewController = UIStoryboard.getController("Profile", vc: "profileVC")
// ERROR: profileviewcontroller does not have a rootview
vc.rootView = true
AppDelegate.rootGotoWithMainNav(vc)
```

Comment: ProfileViewController has to extend UIViewController.

Comment: corrrected. that was in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ProfileViewController` does not have `rootView` property of `mainNavBarItems` protocol.

```
class ProfileViewController:  UIViewController, mainNavBarItems{
    var rootView = false // this is default
    func gotoRootProfileView() {
        // does stuff
    }
}
```

...and Protocol should have capitalized names.

[Protocol as Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID275)